# powershell - storing cmdlet Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation into a variable and then printing it, doesn't give expected output

Tags: powershell

I'm running a DHCP server in Windows Server 2012 R2 with an active scope and I've made a script which asks the user for a MAC address and will then reserve an available ip from the scope to the user's MAC.

The actual reservation works without a problem but I've introduced an *IF ELSE* statement, with the hope that the conditional expression is evaluated as TRUE when a reservation is successful and to FALSE otherwise.

But the expression always evaluates to FALSE because storing the execution of the cmdlet *Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation* into a variable and then printing it, yields a really messed up output: basically it will print "DHCPServerv4Reservation" as many times as reservations present in the scope, instead of the output given when directly executing the cmdlet.

Here's the code:

```
clear-host

$mac=read-host -prompt "Please type the MAC address for the host "

$freeip=Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress -scopeid 10.10.10.0

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 -ClientId $mac -IPAddress $freeip

$reservedips=Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0

if ($reservedips -match $freeip) {

    write-host "The ip $freeip has been succesfully reserved for the host with the MAC address $mac"
}

else {write-host "I'm sorry but there are no free ip addresses to be  reserved"}

# this is just to see what's inside $reservedips
write-host $reservedips
```

Why is this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation` is a reservation object.

The `-match` operator is for matching a string against a regular expression.

You might be looking to something like:

```powershell
if (($reservedips | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress -eq $freeip })) {
    # success
}
```

I think you consider restructuring your code to look something like this:

```powershell
$mac=read-host -prompt "Please type the MAC address for the host "

$freeip=Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress -scopeid 10.10.10.0

try {
    Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 -ClientId $mac -IPAddress $freeip -ErrorAction Stop
} catch {
    Write-Host "An error has occurred while trying to add a reservation for '$mac' with IP '$freeip'."
}
```

Adding `-ErrorAction Stop` forces all exceptions to be caught by the `try`/`catch` block.

Comment: Thanks, I have found an alternative myself, which I'll try to show here somehow

Comment: Yeah, my alternative is very similar to yours. The thing is, I can get the _-match_ operator to work when I store into a variable the contents of a text file by using the _get-content_ cmdlet

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; I don't see a call to `Get-Content` in your code. In any case, you need to be careful about using the `-match` operator to directly compare strings because the right side operator is being interpreted as a regular expression. Consider using `-like` or `-eq` unless you actually want a RegEx match.

Comment: Yeah, i was referring to another script when I made that comment (sorry about that). But it seems like there's a huge difference in terms of how to look for a value when the data ultimately comes from a text file (which I believe, this is not the case) and when it doesn't (which I believe this is the case)

Comment: Anyway, tomorrow I have a final exam on powershell which is actually a recovery exam of yet another recovery exam. I just hope I pass and hopefully, I will never ever have to use this scripting language again...definitely my nemesis

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternative I have come up with, which works

```
clear-host

$mac=read-host -prompt "Please type the MAC address for the host "

$freeip=Get-DhcpServerv4FreeIPAddress -scopeid 10.10.10.0

Add-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 -ClientId $mac -IPAddress $freeip

$reservedips=Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId 10.10.10.0 | Where-Object ipaddress -eq $freeip

if ($reservedips -eq "") {write-host "I'm sorry but there are no free ip addresses to be reserved"}

else {write-host "The ip $freeip has been succesfully reserved for the host with the MAC address $mac"}
```